# Background image gradient overlay not working in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I have written the below html code to make background image with gradient overlay. This is working perfectly as standalone but when I used in wordpress post, its not working. I can see only a blank space.

Hosting: Godaddy Managed WordPress
Browser: Google Chrome
I even tried in Visual Composer -> Raw HTML.
**Link:** http://padals.com/t2/

```
<html>
<head><style>
.bg-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    background: #3e3e3e;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.07) 0 2px 0;
    left: -34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: -34px;
    top: -100px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .bg-img:after {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,.43);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.57) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.21) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.57) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.21) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.57) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.21) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.57) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.21) 100%);
    box-shadow: inset rgba(0,0,0,.26) 0 3px 0,inset rgba(0,0,0,.21) 2px 0 0,inset rgba(0,0,0,.26) 0 -1px 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    }
.bg-img img {
    filter: blur(42px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(42px);
    -moz-filter: blur(42px);
    -ms-filter: blur(42px);
    filter: url(http://static.saavncdn.com/_i/3.0/blur.svg#blur);
    left: 50%;
    margin: -56% 0 0 -56%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 112%;
    z-index: 10;
}
img {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
</style></head>
<body>

<div class="bg-img"><img src="http://padals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Baahubali_poster.jpg" alt="" /></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you see a blank instead of the image or you are getting the image but the gradient is not working ?

Comment: @Dhaval - only blank space not even an image, You can see it i the above mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

try n use this code and see if you get the image first and then you can bother about the gradient working or not..

```
<img src="<?php echo content_url('/uploads/2016/05/my_photo.jpg'); ?>" alt="My Picture">
```

Comment: FYI - php code will not work inside the WordPress page and if I removed the  stylesheet (CSS) then I can see the image.

Comment: php codes will work inside wordpress page to get the right image from the uploads folder and now as you said its a problem of the stylesheet and gradient properties used and we will have to diagnose that and see what can be the issue here

Answer (score 0):

**style.css:446-449:**

```
.td-main-content-wrap,
.td-category-grid {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**style.css:13850-13852:**

```
.post {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Remove the `background-color: #fff;` definition from the `.td-main-content-wrap` and from the `.post`.

You have a negative `z-index` on an `absolute` element and that put's it behind the `.post` and the `td-main-content-wrap`.